# Использование библиотек в проектах на репозитории

Tags: visual-studio, git

Здравствуйте. Я создал свой репозиторий с проектом visual studio и опубликовал его на github. В проект еще до публикации я добавлял свои отдельно написанные библиотеки. Однако, как вы может поняли, эти библиотеки (точнее ссылки) недоступны в локальном репозитории других участников. Как можно решить эту проблему? Я новичок, и с гитом только начал работать.

Comment: Как вы подключали эти библиотеки? Они лежат вместе с проектом в игнорируемых папках или где-то в отдельных папках? Как субмодули git?

Comment: Я их подключал через ссылки->Обзор. То есть сама библиотека в другой папке. Появилась мысль положить библиотеку в папку с проектом и прописать в файле .scproj относительную ссылку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вопрос слишком общий, потому и ответ лишь в виде (не исчерпывающего) списка некоторых рекомендаций:

1. если можно предоставить доступ к исходникам библиотек, то:

   1. можно включить исходный код библиотек непосредственно в данный проект (в под-каталоге, например), и при сборке проекта собирать и библиотеки
   2. можно для каждой библиотеки (или для всех разом) создать отдельное хранилище (репозиторий), включить их в проект в виде [подмодулей](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8) и при сборке проекта собирать и библиотеки
2. если нельзя предоставить доступ к исходникам библиотек, то:

   1. можно при сборке проекта скачивать скомпилированные библиотеки из того места, где вы их разместили (http/ftp/smb/и т.п.)
   2. можно добавить скомпилированные библиотеки в хранилище. это, пожалуй, наихудший вариант: программа *git* весьма плохо приспособлена для управления версиями не-текстовых файлов (как, вероятно, и подавляющее большинство иных [систем управления версиями](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8))
   3. чтобы избежать непосредственного включения не-текстовых файлов внутрь хранилища, можно воспользоваться чем-то наподобие [git-annex](http://git-annex.branchable.com/)